# Volley POST request in loop, ignores everything except last call parameters

Tags: android, android-volley

Long story short, im trying to post some parameters into my server, im doing it with for loop:

```
 public void goForOrder(int sum) {

    for (int i = 0; i < forOrderArrayList.size(); i++)
    {
        ProductForOrder pfo = forOrderArrayList.get(i);
        int branchId = pfo.getBranch(i);
        int quanInBranch = pfo.getQuantity(i);

        if (sum < quanInBranch){
            branch = branchId;
            query();
        }
        else {
           for (int j = 0; j <pfo.getNumOfBranchs(); j++){
               branch = pfo.getIdBranch(j);
               query();

           }
        }

    }

}

public void query(){

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_INDEX,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                        int success = jObj.getInt("success");
                        if (success == 1) {

                        }
                        else {
                            // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            })
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("status", "1");
            params.put("branch", String.valueOf(branch));
            return params;
        }
    };

    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}
```

I really dont know how can it be, but if i go step by step in debug mode ill do get the right values into my db (for example):

branchId = 4;

branchId = 1;

branchId = 2;

But if ill use it in normal mode the string request will apply only the last parameters to ALL previous param's i have sent in this loop into my db:

branchId = 2;

branchId = 2;

branchId = 2;

How can it be??
please help?!

Comment: Volley requests are run asynchronously in another thread. This means that by the time the first request starts, and it's `getParams()` method is invoked, your loop which sets value of branch will end, and so the value of branch will be the last one. I guess best approach would be to pass branch value to `query()` method

Comment: yes yes yes, ty working